# VS 2019 caching dev directory structure in production build using Publish IISProfile?

Tags: c#, .net, webdeploy

I have a .net core asp.net angular web app that I have built and deployed to my hosted site. When I try and access the site I get "HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure" BUT the directory path on the Production server is showing my local development directory path in the error message, this doesn't exist on the server and my hosting company refuse to look further than this error. (probably correctly)

There is no hard coding of any directory path in the code so I'm assuming it is a cache issue.

Could someone shed light on this, does VS2019 cache the dev directory paths on Publish IISProfile method? If so how can I stop this?

I'm totally stumped.

So the hosting company has 'rebooted the server' and now the error message has changed to:

```
2020-10-24 11:07:21.091 +01:00 [INF] Starting Web Host
2020-10-24 11:07:21.529 +01:00 [INF] User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\IWPD_****(******)\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
2020-10-24 11:07:21.597 +01:00 [INF] Starting IdentityServer4 version 3.0.0.0
2020-10-24 11:07:21.737 +01:00 [INF] Configuring local API resource 'COREAPI'.
2020-10-24 11:07:21.747 +01:00 [INF] Configuring client 'CORE'.
2020-10-24 11:07:21.769 +01:00 [FTL] Application startup exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
```

Comment: You probably have a TLS issue and connection is not completing.  This is the 3rd time in the last 10 minutes with same issue.  I've been answering question with this error since August.  See my last response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64510998/get-upn-and-email-address-from-msal-2-0-tokens#comment114070932_64510998

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I'll check that out. Why does the production server error message even know about dev repository directory path though - that is wrong. Unfortunately my hosting company aren't interested in helping until the directory paths are correct - very frustrating indeed.

Comment: The error in link doesn't say a response occurred.  So the failure could be before the request is ever sent.

Comment: Thanks, there is a new error now after hosting company changes. Looks like application starts but there is "no key System.InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified."

It could well be my lack of understanding on how to move DEV version using identity server to production server and the hosting company has less of an idea than me

Comment: Check folder on working machine for C:\Users\IWPD_****(******)\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys.  A IIS clients only have GUEST privileges and cannot access files on the disk.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/default-permissions-user-rights

Answer (score 0):

So the reason my app never worked is because it is a shared hosting service and the hosting company has locked down permissions on IIS and various user accounts.